# UITableView 'reloadSections:' method crash in iOS 9 with EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, exc-bad-access, ios9

I am creating a UITableView with expand and collapse sections. When a section is clicked i am trying to load rows to the section as below

```
MenuItem *menuItem = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];    
[menuItem expandInfoValue].isExpanded = YES; 
NSRange range   = NSMakeRange(indexPath.section, 1);
NSIndexSet *sectionToReload = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
[self.tableView reloadSections:sectionToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

in the number of rows In section

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    MenuItem *menuItem = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:section];

    if([menuItem expandInfoValue].isExpanded)
        return [[[self.menuItems objectAtIndex:section] subMenuItems] count];
    else
        return 0;
}
```

The above code is working fine in iOS8.0. But when i run the code on iOS9,

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:sectionToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

crashes with EXEC_BAD_ACCESS with no crash log. 
Can some one point me in correct direction on what might be the issue?
Thanks in advance.

*****Adding back trace as suggested by Philip****

```
* thread #1: tid = 0xb5883, 0x000000010d6129b5 UIKit`__46-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]_block_invoke + 94, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffff8)
    frame #0: 0x000000010d6129b5 UIKit`__46-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]_block_invoke + 94
    frame #1: 0x000000010d612b1b UIKit`__46-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:]_block_invoke1004 + 241
    frame #2: 0x000000010d612245 UIKit`-[UITableView _updateWithItems:updateSupport:] + 2686
    frame #3: 0x000000010d60ae15 UIKit`-[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 15344
    frame #4: 0x000000010d621327 UIKit`-[UITableView _updateSections:updateAction:withRowAnimation:headerFooterOnly:] + 403
  * frame #5: 0x000000010a7a9019 MenuListApp`-[BehindPanelViewController resetPrevSelectedSectionHeaderView](self=0x00007fe1dae09b10, _cmd="resetPrevSelectedSectionHeaderView") + 185 at BehindPanelViewController.m:757
    frame #6: 0x000000010a7a839d MenuListApp`-[BehindPanelViewController menuItemSectionHeaderTapped:](self=0x00007fe1dae09b10, _cmd="menuItemSectionHeaderTapped:", gestureRecognizer=0x00007fe1dacd3c10) + 285 at BehindPanelViewController.m:698
    frame #7: 0x000000010d9a4b40 UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerSendTargetActions + 153
    frame #8: 0x000000010d9a16af UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 162
    frame #9: 0x000000010d99ff01 UIKit`-[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 822
    frame #10: 0x000000010d9a73f3 UIKit`___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke809 + 79
    frame #11: 0x000000010d9a7291 UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 342
    frame #12: 0x000000010d998eb4 UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 2624
    frame #13: 0x000000010d554592 UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1137
    frame #14: 0x000000010d555681 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 849
    frame #15: 0x000000010d507752 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    frame #16: 0x000000010a62cdde MenuListApp`-[TimerUIApplication sendEvent:](self=0x00007fe1d8613170, _cmd="sendEvent:", event=0x00007fe1d8707cd0) + 78 at TimerUIApplication.m:36
    frame #17: 0x000000010d4e2fcc UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6693
    frame #18: 0x000000010f4aa0a1 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    frame #19: 0x000000010f49ffcc CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    frame #20: 0x000000010f49f483 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 867
    frame #21: 0x000000010f49ee98 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    frame #22: 0x0000000111103ad2 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #23: 0x000000010d4e8676 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 171
    frame #24: 0x000000010a6265c7 MenuListApp`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff555df568) + 151 at main.m:15
    frame #25: 0x000000010fd3492d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #26: 0x000000010fd3492d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: When it crashes, type "bt" in the debug console at the "(lldb)" prompt.  Add the stack trace to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try encapsulating your section reload statement inside `[self.tableview beginUpdates]` and `[self.tableview endUpdates]`:

```
[self.tableview beginUpdates]
MenuItem *menuItem = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];    
[menuItem expandInfoValue].isExpanded = YES; 
NSRange range   = NSMakeRange(indexPath.section, 1);
NSIndexSet *sectionToReload = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:range];
[self.tableView reloadSections:sectionToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableview endUpdates]
```

Comment: As a side note, could you also try calling `[self.tableview reloadData]` instead. Of-course that would come with a side effect that entire table would be reloaded.

Comment: Thanks abhinav, already tried it and haven't worked. 'reloadData' is not an option for me. I even tried 'insertRowsAtIndexPaths' but even that is crashing the app

Comment: @LakshmiSandeepKandula Hi, I am facing a similar issue. How did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try reloading tableview before reloading section as follows:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

If this doesn't solve you problem try using `[tableview beginUpdates]` and `[tableview endUpdates]` methods just before and after reloading your section as follows:

```
[tableview beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableview endUpdates];
```

I faced similar issue and it got solved with this solutions. Hope this will help you :)